# Javascript use variable to call another variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making something in React Native and there's a module where I have a variable called `jorge`

```
const jorge = "This is some output"; 
console.log(jorge);            //output: 'This is some output'
```

I've passed props `item` to this module (I'm using the `react-native-router-flux` module, which also has a value of `jorge`:

```
<Scene
    key="sceneTwo"
    component={componentItem}
    title={content.title}
    item="jorge"
 />
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
console.log(this.props.item);  //output: 'This is some output'
```

Whereas in reality, I get this:

```
console.log(this.props.item);  //output: 'jorge'
```

I'm not sure what this technique is called hence the extremely vague title, but if anyone can suggest how I'd tackle this I'd be very grateful!

Comment: are you passing `'jorge'` or `jorge` as the prop?

Comment: How did you pass it?

Comment: You can't really get a variable that way. Is `jorge` the property of an object (i.e., you can access it using `obj.jorge`)? Perhaps `window.jorge`? Then you can access it via "bracket syntax" like `org[this.props.item]`.

Comment: Updated code to clarify (thank you for the quick responses!)

Comment: This is one of those things like when you get to the point where you want your car to be able to pump water out of itself so you can get to the other side of the river. The real problem is that a design mistake was made a few steps back.

Comment: You are passing it as a string, you need to pass it as a variable. Where is jorge being defined?

Comment: <Scene
    key="sceneTwo"
    component={componentItem}
    title={content.title}
    item={jorge}
 />

Look at curly braces around jorge. I assume that jorge is in the scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your are passing the string `"jorge"` rather than the variable `jorge`.  To pass a variable you need to wrap it in curly brackets:

```
<Scene
    key="sceneTwo"
    component={componentItem}
    title={content.title}
    item={jorge}
 />
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that variable jorje is within the scope of the of the usage of eval, this should work:

```
 console.log(eval(this.props.item))
```

Here is a sample use of eval with an abbreviated object containing your values:

```
const jorje = "This is some output";

var scene = {key:'sceneTwo', item:'jorje'};

console.log( scene.item ); // outputs jorje

console.log( eval( scene.item ));  //outputs This is some output
```